# How can I find the source for Android 2.3.3 Platform?

Tags: android, android-source

When in debug mode I get a source not found message for the android stuff.  I am using Andorid-10 to match my device.  In the 'android-sdk\sources' I have android-14 and Android-15. How and where can I get the Andorid-10 source tree.  I have looked at 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.3.html  but I can't find a source to download.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best answer for me is going to http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/ 
and downloading the Eclipse plugin for **Android Sources**. To get the plugin,
in Eclipse select the 'help' button and select 'install new software'.  Then give it 
http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/
It is a big down load, but after Eclipse has all the source code.

Thanks for your help

Cliff

Answer (score 8):

I use [grepcode](http://grepcode.com) to browse and download android source code.
You can find a jar with android 2.3 [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1). You should also be able to download the source code from https://github.com/android and http://code.google.com/p/android/.

Comment: You'll need the [`platform_frameworks_base` project's `core/java/android` folder](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/android-2.3.3_r1.1/core/java/android) and then select a Tag on top.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to have the Android-10 SDK available to build code against for writing Java applications. With that assumption, the way to get Android-10 support is to use:

```
android-sdk/tools/android
```

This will load the Android SDK and AVD Manager. Use the 'Available packages' menu selection and proceed to the Android-10 SDK download.

Comment: I have the Android-10 jar. I just need the source.  Cliff

Comment: Well almost. I downloaded the android-2.3.3_r1-sources.jar file.  When I try to execute it, I get a Java exception.  Cliff

Comment: The **source** for Android-10 is not available in the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone --no-checkout https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore
cd libcore
git tag -l | grep -F 2.3.

android-2.3.1_r1
android-2.3.2_r1
android-2.3.3_r1
android-2.3.3_r1.1
android-2.3.4_r0.9
android-2.3.4_r1
android-2.3.5_r1
android-2.3.6_r0.9
android-2.3.6_r1
android-2.3.7_r1
```

pick your preferred version, just a note: the emulator image of `platform-10` is android 2.3.4 (look at `adb shell getprop`)

```
git checkout android-2.3.4_r1
cd luni/src/main/java
jar cvf <android sdk>/platforms/android-10/sources.jar *
```

now you can attach the jar to eclipse