# THEME IS TOTALLY DIFFERENT WHEN COMPARE LOLLIPOP AND KITKAT, JELLY BEAN

Tags: android

I use  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme` in our xml for the `Edittext` field as square box.

But in jellybean and kitkat OS the default line will come.

> How do I use the same theme that was supported for all OS in android?

I want the Edit text field to be square.

Comment: Based on the text in the body I can only assume you're caps-lock key isn't broken. So please don't write titles in all caps

Comment: "But in jellybean and kitkat OS the default line will come" -- please explain what you mean by this. You may wish to capture some screenshots, upload them somewhere, and link to the from your question, to illustrate what you are seeing.

Comment: Jellybean and other older OS the style what i give is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same theme on all versions of Android, you need to create your own instead of inheriting from the system theme which can and does change from one version to the next.

e.g In your example, you could copy the Gingerbread EditText theme into your own project and then use that rather than the system theme for an ExitText. That way you would get the square white boxes with an orange highlight instead of the later themes which use only a coloured line.

You can get the theme and the related drawables from the source code.

[How can I find the source for Android 2.3.3 Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875082/how-can-i-find-the-source-for-android-2-3-3-platform)